# Separar un string y convertirlo en array para JSON leible

Tags: javascript

soy nuevo en esto y necesito ayuda.

Tengo un JSON que se genera automático por un sistema y es recibido por GET.

```
{
    "data": "key=g8g5h, age=6, key=vgj76, age=45, key=drk1e, age=36, ... key=fh5y3, age=32,"
}
```

Necesito convertirlo en un arreglo y devolverlo mejor formateado en JSON algo así:

```
{
    "data": [
        {"key":"g8g5h", "age":6},
        {"key":"vgj76", "age":45},
        {"key":"drk1e", "age"36},
        {....},
        {"key":"fh5y3", "age":32},
    ]
}
```

¿Cómo podría realizarlo o llegar a lo mas parecido?
El Lenguaje que estoy usando es JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes intentar parsear el string que te llega con una expresión regular:

- `.match(/key=(\w+)[, ]+age=(\d+)/g)` separa la cadena completa de `data` en strings que contiene un solo campo `key` y un solo campo `age`.
- Ahora con un `reduce`, cada vamos recorriendo la lista de elementos `key=?, age=?` de manera que obtenemos el valor de cada uno y lo agregamos a un array.

Una posible solución podría ser:

```js
let response = {
    "data": "key=g8g5h, age=6, key=vgj76, age=45, key=drk1e, age=36, key=fh5y3, age=32,"
}

let data = response.data.match(/key=(\w+)[, ]+age=(\d+)/g)
    .reduce((acc, pair) => {
        const fields = pair.match(/key=(\w+)[, ]+age=(\d+)/); 
        const key = fields[1]; 
        const age = Number.parseInt(fields[2]);
        acc.push({key, age});
        return acc
    }, []);

let json = {data}
console.log(json);
```

Una respuesta alternativa utilizando solo un ciclo `for`:

```js
let response = {
    "data": "key=g8g5h, age=6, key=vgj76, age=45, key=drk1e, age=36, key=fh5y3, age=32,"
}

let matches = response.data.match(/((?<=key=)\w+)|((?<=age=)\d+)/g)

let data = []
for (let i = 0; i < matches.length; i = i + 2) {
    data.push({
        key: matches[i],
        age: Number.parseInt(matches[i + 1])
    })
}

let json = {data}
console.log(json);
```

Comment: Excelente, solucionado, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Una opción podría ser la siguiente:

```
const original = {
  data: "key=g8g5h, age=6, key=vgj76, age=45, key=drk1e, age=36"
};


let temp1 = original.data.split(/[, ]+/) //Remueve "," and " "

//arma array de claves y valores por separado
let temp2 = temp1.map(item=>item.split("="))

let result = {data: []} //Doy estructura del objeto
for(let i=0;i<temp2.length;i+=2){ //Recorro cada 2 elementos
let obj = {} //Objeto auxiliar
obj[temp2[i][0]] = temp2[i][1] //Armo la primer parte del objeto
obj[temp2[i+1][0]] = temp2[i+1][1] // Armo segunda parte del objeto
result.data.push(obj) //Agrego objeto completo a result
}

console.log(result) // Muestro result
```

**Resultado obtenido:**

```
{
data: 
0: {key: 'g8g5h', age: '6'}
1: {key: 'vgj76', age: '45'}
2: {key: 'drk1e', age: '36'}
}
```

---

La otra opción podría ser encontrar los keys y los age por separado, y luego unirlos en objetos, para esto podrías utilizar expresiones regulares o recorrerlos y ver si existe esa palabra en cada item.